# Perfect forwarder in Herb Sutter's C++Con 2014 talk

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference, function-templates

In [Herb Sutter's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64) at C++Con 2014, among other things he discusses passing by value, by reference, and so forth. One technique he presents in this albeit contrived example is:

```
using namespace std;

class employee{
    string name_;
public:
    template<class String, class = enable_if_t<!is_same<decay_t<String>, string>::value>>

    void set_name(String&& name) noexcept(is_nothrow_assignable<string&, String>::value){
        name_ = forward<String>(name);
    }
};
```

I understand that `String&&`is a *universal* or *forwarding* reference as `String` is a deduced template type, and that one should therefore use `forward<String>(name)`. Whilst I have some very limited experience with template metaprogramming, it is not obvious to me what is the purpose of the unamed tempate parameter, with the `enable_if_t...` and would appreciate an explanation to decipher its purpose. How does the `noexcept` work? What would have been wrong if one had naively written:

```
template<class String>
void set_name(String&& name){
    name_ = forward<String>(name);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to ensure that `set_name` is only called with an l- or r-value reference to a `std::string`, allowing for any cv-qualifiers.

It works using SFINAE: if the result of `decay`ing the `String` template argument is not the same type as `std::string`, `enable_if_t` will fail type checking, so that template will be removed from the candidate set.

Comment: One note, is if you watch the video, the "slide" version shows it as `!is_same`, where if you look at it over his shoulder as he's talking, it's just `is_same`.  I suspect he wanted the `is_same` version.  This is around 1:17:00 in the video.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I assumed, otherwise the code seems rather strange.

Comment: Just a note to explain the decay_t part: decay_t<String> is the type you pass by value when you pass a String to a function. So the enable_if (when corrected to remove the "!") makes it so that set_name exists only when used with a type that will be std::string as it is passed into a function by value but acts as if there are no implicit conversions to std::string. This isn't the best example as I think most users would want to use set_name on any type that can be assigned to an instance of std::string - I don't mean to be critical of it but I hope that brings some perspective to the example.

Answer (score 1):

This unnamed template parameter is required because of `std::enable_if_t` usage. Parameter is not needed (used inside template function), so it can be unnamed.

`std::enable_if_t` works using [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error). If the parameter of `std::enable_if_t` is false, the code for function will not be generated for that parameter.

See [some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) for more information about `std::enable_if_t`. You can also look at [Template Meta-Programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Templates/Template_Meta-Programming) wikibook or [SFINAE and enable_if](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/sfinae-and-enable_if/) article.